# Firebase Notification not working when sending notification from server in swift 4?

Tags: ios, firebase, push-notification, apple-push-notifications, swift4

I am creating a push notification for my project in swift 4. The pushed message from the firebase console is shown on my iphone but the message pushed from the server-side is not delivered to my iphone. I need to post fcm_token to server at login. My code is:

AppDelegate

```
import UIKit
import CoreData
import CoreLocation
import FBSDKCoreKit
import FBSDKLoginKit
import UserNotifications
import Firebase
import FirebaseInstanceID
import FirebaseMessaging

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate, UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate, MessagingDelegate {

  var window: UIWindow?
  var locationManager: CLLocationManager!
  var notificationCenter: UNUserNotificationCenter!

  func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.

    self.locationManager = CLLocationManager()
    self.locationManager!.delegate = self

    // get the singleton object
    self.notificationCenter = UNUserNotificationCenter.current()

    // register as it's delegate
    notificationCenter.delegate = self

    // define what do you need permission to use
    let options: UNAuthorizationOptions = [.alert, .sound]

    // request permission
    notificationCenter.requestAuthorization(options: options) { (granted, error) in
      if !granted {
        print("Permission not granted")
      }
    }

    if launchOptions?[UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey.location] != nil {
      print("I woke up thanks to geofencing")
    }

    // Messaging.messaging().delegate = self

    if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
      // For iOS 10 display notification (sent via APNS)
      UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self
      let authOptions: UNAuthorizationOptions = [.alert, .badge, .sound]
      UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(
        options: authOptions,
        completionHandler: {_, _ in })
      // For iOS 10 data message (sent via FCM
      Messaging.messaging().delegate = self
    } else {
      let settings: UIUserNotificationSettings =
        UIUserNotificationSettings(types: [.alert, .badge, .sound], categories: nil)
      application.registerUserNotificationSettings(settings)
    }
    application.registerForRemoteNotifications()
    FirebaseApp.configure()
    return true
  }

  func application(_ application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: Data) {

    InstanceID.instanceID().instanceID { (result, error) in
      if let error = error {
        print("Error fetching remote instange ID: \(error)")
      } else if let result = result {
        print("Remote instance ID token: \(result.token)")

        UserDefaults.standard.set(result.token, forKey: "FCM_Token")
        UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()
      }
    }
    }
```

And I have uploaded p12 certificates to firebase console. Do backend developer need to install pem certificates on the server as the push notification's message are sent through the server?

Comment: If the message works from the console but not the server, then there is likely an issue with the server code. Please update your question to include the code used to send the message from the server. Also, just to clarify, when sending a message from the console, are you sending to the specific FCM token, or to the whole app?

Comment: do they need to install pem file of development and distribution on the server? @Jen Person

Comment: I am also facing the same issue. Suddenly push notifications stopped coming from the server but work when I send notification from firebase console(not on specific FCM token). @SwiftGuy did you find any solution?